# PHP with Oracle - Error 12537 (TNS:connection closed)

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to use PHP with Oracle 11g. I have configured the php.ini file (enabled php_oci8.dll, php_oci8_11g.dll)

This is the testing code I'm using:

```
if ($conn = oci_connect('system', 'pass', '//localhost:1158/em')) {
    print 'Successfully connected to Oracle Database XE!';
    oci_close($conn);
} else {
    $errmsg = oci_error();
    print 'Oracle connect error: ' . $errmsg['message'];
}
?>
```

But I'm getting this error:
Oracle connect error:

```
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed
```

Any solution?

Comment: Are you able to connect to Oracle via SQL Developer or SQL*Plus?

Comment: solved it.. It should have used the correct sid (orcl in my case).. also the port number i entered was wrong..